# SwiftUI transition is not working properly

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to make a transition from bottom edge to top when a view appears.

```
 ZStack{
   VStack {
    .
    .//other components
    .
    if self.modalShown {
        HStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                BottomSheetView(
                    isOpen: self.$modalShown,
                    maxHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.6
                ) {
                    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                        FiltersView(hideControl: self.$modalShown)
                            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    }

                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                }
            }
        }
        .accessibility(identifier: "modalFilterView")
    } 
}
```

The problem is that when this view appears, it performs a kind of alpha 0 to alpha 1 transition. And when the view is dismissed it does not perform any transition.

Could be related this undesired behavior with the zIndex?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the transition modifier was in the wrong place:

```
 ZStack{
   VStack {
    .
    .//other components
    .
    if self.modalShown {
        HStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                BottomSheetView(
                    isOpen: self.$modalShown,
                    maxHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.6
                ) {
                    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                        FiltersView(hideControl: self.$modalShown)
                    }
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                }
            }
        }
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        .accessibility(identifier: "modalFilterView")
    } 
}
```